# Web service reference cannot work when run with windows service?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, windows-services

I have third party web service and I am developing windows service. When my windows service, it needs to request to web service to get and send some data. 
In windows service I added web service reference by using it's URL.
It works in debug mode, the windows service can get and set data to web service.
But when I install the windows service using `installutil windowsService.exe` and start the service by command `sc start windowsService`, error happen:

System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException

Error Message:
There was no endpoint listening at http://webservice/service.svc/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I have no clue @@. 
Please help!

Comment: Well, is the reported address correct?  What is in the inner exception?

Comment: It might be a privileges problem, install the service under another account (yours) to test. Then solve it by configuring the WinService account

Comment: where is your webservice? same server? does it need a proxy? when you run it in debug, how are you running it? running it as you perhaps?

Comment: Maybe the account hosting the windows service does not have the same proxy settings as your own account?

Comment: I would like that you could share more details about the Debug process. If the service works in debug mode, how could the service throw the EndpointNotFoundException error? As for the error, it suggests we correct the service endpoint address in configuration file. Besides, there may exist access privilege problem in the process, by default windows account may be used during the authentication process. So try to change the windows NT service running account to specified account.